# Does crossing out "Project Phoenix" have some meaning?

Tags: avatar-the-way-of-water

The Recombinant soliders appear to have been created by something called Project Phoenix.

The project name is shown on some of the uniforms the wear. The name appears to have been lightly crossed out on the Colonel's uniform.

[image: Project Phoenix X]

Is this just more reinforcement of the phoenix motif? Phoenix for rebirth initially preparing the save-points and the crossing out to indicate the original died? Or is this crossing out particular/personal to the Colonel?

Comment: It's on other items. It appears to just be styling; https://preview.redd.it/att5e24y2f191.png?width=400&format=png&auto=webp&v=enabled&s=5eec693d7d14ec854a9c0aa6bef29c7664f3cab7 / https://james-camerons-avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Lopez